# Application using SAPUI5, HANA and Java

Tags: java, sapui5, hana

I need to create an application with

Front end: SAPUI5,
Back end: Java(springboot,or any advanced technologies),
data base: to be linked to HANA to fetch the data.

Is this possible by any way? 
Main aim is to use SAPUI5, Java and HANA together.

Answer (score 1):

Java Springboot is included with XS Advanced applications for HANA. You can check this blog for details and a demo video: https://blogs.sap.com/2017/04/18/sap-hana-2.0-sps-01-new-developer-features/

In case yo want to give it a try, you can get SAP HANA + XS Advanced applications for free up to 32 GB using HANA express edition, registering and downloading here: https://www.sap.com/developer/topics/sap-hana-express.html

Answer (score 0):

It is possible.

Regards, Nikita